# Wrong number of arguments Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

[Screenshot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCzSr.png)

I keep getting this error message. I am trying to add the ability to upload an image to an instagram clone

Comment: Please don't post images of error messages - makes your question irrelevant to anyone in the future who may be experiencing the same issue.

Comment: Your question is likely being downvoted because it doesn't show that you attempted to resolve your issue. In the future, show what you may have tried prior to reaching out to us for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message

This method takes two arguments. What you want is probably the `full_messages()` method, which doesn't take any argument and returns an array of all the messages, for you to assign each one with a `<li>`. So just add a s, adapt your code to the iteration in an array and that may do the job :)